# create a virtual floppy image without mount?

Tags: linux, sudo, mount, dd, floppy

There are a lot of posts to show to create a virtual floppy image file as a super user or users can run `sudo` command. The basic steps are:

1. create empty 1.44MB image file by `dd` command
2. format the image file by `mkfs.msdos`
3. mount the image file to some mount point
4. copy something to the mount point
5. `umount` the virtual floppy image file

my question is, in case I am just a common user who cannot run `sudo` command, how can I follow above steps to create a virtual floppy image and write something in it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, of course you can do this. Use `mtools` for the FAT and `e2tools` or `genext2fs` for the ext2 filesystems.

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/disk1.img count=1440 bs=1k 
1440+0 records in
1440+0 records out
1474560 bytes (1.5 MB) copied, 0.00569719 s, 259 MB/s

$ /sbin/mkfs.msdos /tmp/disk1.img 
mkfs.msdos 3.0.12 (29 Oct 2011)

$ mdir -i /tmp/disk1.img
 Volume in drive : has no label
 Volume Serial Number is 9913-BFF6
Directory for ::/

No files
                          1 457 664 bytes free

$ mcopy -i /tmp/disk1.img /etc/issue.net ::/
$ mdir -i /tmp/disk1.img
 Volume in drive : has no label
 Volume Serial Number is 9913-BFF6
Directory for ::/

issue    net        28 2012-06-26  10:49 
        1 file                   28 bytes
                          1 457 152 bytes free
```

And of course, I have no root rights.

Comment: Although `mdir` command not works for me, `mcopy` does work. Thank you.

Comment: Very elegant and simple solution. It worked very well to make an image for use in VirtualBox image of DOS 6.22.

Comment: how do I make this bootable?

Comment: @Blub: Use for example FreeDOS for that

Comment: For a DOS filesystem, you can combine the image/filesystem create with `mkfs.msdos -C /tmp/disk1.img 1440`. Where `-C ` will *"Create  the  file  given as device on the command line."*

Comment: You don't need `mkfs.vfat`. mtools includes an `mformat` command.